# Cannot get my div to move(position)

Tags: css, positioning

I'm doing my first piece of HTML & CSS today, and I'm having trouble trying to move a `div`. I read some tutorials on CSS and tried to replicate what I've seen. But for some reason I cannot get the `div` to move.

Can anybody set me straight as to what I've done wrong please?

CSS

```
#seax {
  position:static;
  top:400;
  left:400;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="seax">
  <form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="/search.html">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Search:</td>
          <td>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" size="40" name="for" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
             &nbsp;&nbsp; 
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="brand" value="0">
            <input type="image" src="/user/templates/custom/search.gif" value="Go" alt="Go" style="padding: 0px">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Just quick advice - try from the start to code with `div`s and to avoid `table` for design. Use tables just to show some data. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 2):

Change `position:static;` to `position:relative;`. Static position displays the div in it's default position, which is as it'd appear in the document flow you see.

Comment: I think the question is a little unclear as to whether the position should be relative or absolute, but the issue definitely is with position:static;

Comment: @JosephSzymborski yes I agree. With the html given though, either one will allow positioning accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Give the `div` a `position` of `absolute`

```
#seax {
  position: absolute;
  top:400;
  left:400;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "px" to your CSS, and use absolute

```
#seax {
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/tnvQz/

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you want to position the div.

`position: static;` is definitely your issue, as static position (as @Omega noted) displays the div in it's default position. You mean to write either `position: absolute` or `position: relative`. The difference between the two is best outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426497/position-relative-vs-position-absolute) but I'll give you a tl;dr.

`position: absolute` positions the div relative to the whole page, whereas `position: relative` positions it relative to the parent.

Also, you are missing `px` at the end of your `top` and `left` property values (i.e `top:10px;` and `left:10px;`)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<div id="seax"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="seax"></div>
```

and

```
#seax {
position:static;
top:400;
left:400;
 }
```

to

```
.seax {
 position:absolute;
 top:400px;
 left:400px;
}
```

if you want to use `seax` for multiple elements.

You could even try:

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="/search.html">
  <div class="seax">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Search:</td>
          <td>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" size="40" name="for" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
             &nbsp;&nbsp; 
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="brand" value="0">
            <input type="image" src="/user/templates/custom/search.gif" value="Go" alt="Go" style="padding: 0px">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

That should fix it. Otherwise your HTML document should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <style>
   .seax {
    position:absolute;
    top:400px;
    left:400px;
    }
</style>
<body>

<div class="seax">
 <form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="/search.html">
  <table>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>Search:</td>
       <td>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" size="40" name="for" class="ui-
autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-
autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
         &nbsp;&nbsp; 
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="brand" value="0">
        <input type="image" src="/user/templates/custom/search.gif" 
   value="Go" alt="Go" style="padding: 0px">
         </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
   </form>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```