# JQueryUI: Sliding two divs at the same time

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a web page where I have two divs that take up the full space. I want to show them one at a time with a JQueryUI slide transition between them so that one div slides away to the left and is replaced by the other div sliding in from the right.
Unfortunately, right now, since both the animations occur at the same time, the second div appears below the first div and then slides up to replace the first div at the end of the animation. How do I position the second div so that the sliding motion happens seamlessly?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#schedule').hide();
    $( '#changer' ).click(function() {
            $("#roster").toggle( "slide", {direction: "left"}, "fast" );
            $("#schedule").toggle("slide", { direction: "right"}, "fast");

            if ($("#changer").html() == 'Schedule View')
                $("#changer").html('Roster View');
            else
                $("#changer").html("Schedule View");
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FkNa2/2/

The relevant code is the css positioning,

```
// html
<p>some content here </p>
<div class="container">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
<button>Toggle</button>

// css
#div1{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#div2{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.container {
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

The trick is to ensure that both the divs will occupy the same position in the viewport. That is done by **absolutely** positioning both of them to the same coordinates. Note that these coordinates are relative to the outer div. Refer the answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/10426717/30007

> Both “relative” and “absolute” positioning are really relative, just
>   with different framework. “Absolute” positioning is relative to the
>   position of another, enclosing element. “Relative” positioning is
>   relative to the position that the element itself would have without
>   positioning.
>
> It depends on your needs and goals which one you use. “Relative”
>   position is suitable when you wish to displace an element from the
>   position it would otherwise have in the flow of elements, e.g. to make
>   some characters appear in a superscript position. “Absolute”
>   positioning is suitable for placing an element in some system of
>   coordinates set by another element, e.g. to “overprint” an image with
>   some text.
>
> As a special, use “relative” positioning with no displacement (just
>   setting position: relative) to make an element a frame of reference,
>   so that you can use “absolute” positioning for elements that are
>   inside it (in markup).

Answer (score 0):

Set the `z-index` ([w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)) of the div higher.

You can see this as layers of a website. for example 0 comes on the bottom 10 comes on the top.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The problem is that while the animation is happening, div2 is below div1 so that for a short period of time my web page is twice its normal height. When div1 has slid out completely, div2 abruptly jumps up to occupy its place.