# CSS Absolute Position Div vs P

Tags: css

I ran into an issue with absolute position with a nested `p` tag.  [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rGTL/1/) demonstrates the difference.  Based on the description on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426497/position-relative-vs-position-absolute) and the comment by user1334007 absolute positioning is relative to the first parent.  Even though [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) does not state that, it appears to be the case for `div` tags.  For `p` tags, it seems that absolute is relative to the page as Michael Zaporozhets states in the SO answer and w3school describes.

**With all these links in mind, am I making a mistake with my styles somewhere or are these performing differently?  If they perform differently, can someone offer an explanation as to why this happens please?**  The main reason I am asking is this is a question in the 70-480 certification tests and even though I know the answer the say is correct, I would like to be able to use positioning with confidence going forward.

Code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rGTL/1/) link (required to have code to submit jsfiddle link so i just put it all in)

```
<h2>Paragraph Position</h2>
<p class="outer">Hello Outer
    <p class="inner">Hello Inner</p>
</p>
<br/>

<h2>Division Position</h2>
<div class="outer">Hello Outer
    <div class="inner">Hello Inner</div>
</div>

.outer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
}

.inner {

    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the HTML (I looked with Chrome Inspector), you'll see that `p.inner` isn't actually inside `p.outer`. Because of this, `p.inner` will be absolutely positioned relative to the first parent element that has `relative` positioning or the `html` tag (in this case the `html` tag).

Edit: I looked in Firefox as well and it seems as if these browsers will convert nested `p` tags into separate `p` tags. So a `p` tag inside of another `p` tag will result in three sibling `p` tags.

Comment: I did notice that, it kind of created an extra set p tags before and after.  I forgot to mention that.  Is that normal with nested p tags?

Comment: After edit: It does this with IE 11 as well. But that defiantly explains why this is not going off the parent tag.  Ill create another question, why html does not do what I tell it to do ;).

Comment: @JabberwockyDecompiler Yes, it seems as if current browser standards make it so that `p` tags will be automatically closed (see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong)

Comment: +1 As stated in [W3's specs for HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-p-element), it might be different soon!

Comment: @JabberwockyDecompiler If you really need a block element inside of a paragraph tag, you can change the css for a tag that can go inside of a `p` tag (e.g. add the rule `display: block` to a `span` tag) - http://jsfiddle.net/8rGTL/2/

Comment: @Dennis I am not trying to get this to work for a webpage, this was a question on a practice test and I wanted to cover my bases by doing a demo.  Personally, I would never place a p inside a p, unless I had a specific requirement.  But you know how MS tests can go, they are not always written by the experts :D.  Thank you for your help.