# Positioning the div elements

Tags: html, css

I am facing the problem to align the content div in a data div.  The Data div was not fixed
height. Because it was auto height when the content div increase.

But it was going to out of flow. How to solve it ?

```css
.container
{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid blue;
  margin:auto;
  width:200px;
}

.data
{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid green;
  width:100px;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
}

.hed
{
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid orange;
  width:30px;
  height:10px;
  top:-5px;
  left:10px;
  border-radius:5px;
  background-color:orange;
  line-height:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="data"> This is absolute.</div>
  <div class="hed">xxx</div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your code??

Comment: [link]   (http://jsfiddle.net/sai070cm118/m08bL4cb/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the `container` expand as the `data` div expands, add `<br style = "clear:both">` before the closing `div` tag.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m08bL4cb/3/)

Comment: I am confusing about the position property. could you please give any reference link to differentiate the relative and absolute.

Comment: [Position Relative vs Position Absolute?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10426566/2851845)

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to the "container" div

Comment: It require to extend.

Comment: @user3836476: check my answer it will expand on addding more data

Answer (score 0):

change all `css` position to `relative` and use `min-height` then try

like this

```
.container {
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid blue;
    margin:auto;
    width:200px;
    min-height:10px; //added
}
.data {
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid green;
    width:100px;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
.hed {
    position:relative;  //changed
    border:1px solid orange;
    width:30px;
    height:10px;
    top:-50px; //changed
    left:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:orange;
    line-height:10px;
}
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m08bL4cb/6/)

Comment: I am confusing about the position property. could you please give any reference link to when we use absolute and when we use relative.

Comment: @user3836476: did my answer give you the right answer ??

Comment: @user3836476: go through this https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/  and understand

Comment: @user3836476 then please accept my answer by clicking the arrow to the left of my answer,thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using for **div class="data"**:

- top
- left

You juste need to replace them by **margin-top** and **margin-left**.

```css
.container
{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid blue;
  margin:auto;
  width:200px;
}

.data
{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid green;
  width:100px;
  margin-top:10px; // changed
  margin-left:10px; // changed
}

.hed
{
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid orange;
  width:30px;
  height:10px;
  top:-5px;
  left:10px;
  border-radius:5px;
  background-color:orange;
  line-height:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="data"> This is absolute.</div>
  <div class="hed">xxx</div>
</div>
```