# Why does this relatively positioned element render below its parent?

Tags: html, css, css-position

[**JSFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7dte3ru6/4/)

In this SSCCE, the first `div.number-outer-container` renders below its parent `div.step-container`.

[image]

**The question is that why is this happening, and what can I do to make it render vertically at the right place?**

I have tried to apply a `top:0` to `div.number-outer-container` but it does not seem to affect anything.

***Note:*** This is just an SSCCE, actually each `div.step-container` is added dynamically, and any number of  `div.step-container`s can be added.

```css
.wrapper-big {
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 826px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: table;
  background-color: #003b80;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.left-cell {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: chocolate;
}
.right-cell {
  background-color: darkslategrey
}
.step-container {
  max-height: 200px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.right-cell .step-container {
  margin-top: 125px;
  direction: rtl;
}
.content-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  /*border: 5px solid blue;*/
  font-size: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69);
  background-color: dodgerblue
}
.right-cell .content-box {
  background-color: darkturquoise
}
.middle-cell {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  width: 1.5px;
  font-size: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}
.number-outer-container {
  display: inline-block;
  /*position:absolute;*/
  position: relative;
  left: 390px;
}
.left-cell .number-outer-container {
  /*margin-left:39px;*/
}
.left-cell .number-outer-container {
  left:390px;
}
.right-cell .number-outer-container {
  right:390px;
}
.number-inner-container {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.number-banner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: crimson;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size:22px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:white;
  line-height:50px;
  text-align:center;
}
.notch-outer-container {
  display: inline-block;
}
.left-cell .notch-outer-container {
  /*margin-right: 24px;*/
}
.right-cell .notch-outer-container {
  /*margin-left: 22px;*/
}
.notch-inner-container {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.notch {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
}
.left-face-notch {
  border-right: 15px solid #520f23;
}
.right-face-notch {
  border-left: 15px solid #571780;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-big">

  <div class="wrapper">


    <div class="cell left-cell" align="left">
      <!-- -->
      <div class="step-container">
        <div class="content-box"></div>



        <div class="notch-outer-container">
          <div class="notch-inner-container">
            <div class="right-face-notch notch"></div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="number-outer-container">
          <div class="number-inner-container">
            <div class="number-banner">1</div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- -->

      <div class="step-container" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <div class="content-box"></div>



        <div class="notch-outer-container">
          <div class="notch-inner-container">
            <div class="right-face-notch notch"></div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="number-outer-container">
          <div class="number-inner-container">
            <div class="number-banner">3</div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- -->

      <div class="step-container" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <div class="content-box"></div>



        <div class="notch-outer-container">
          <div class="notch-inner-container">
            <div class="right-face-notch notch"></div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="number-outer-container">
          <div class="number-inner-container">
            <div class="number-banner">5</div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- -->
    </div>



    <div class="cell middle-cell"></div>



    <div class="cell right-cell" align="right">
      <!-- -->
      <div class="step-container" style="margin-top:125px;">

        <div class="content-box"></div>



        <div class="notch-outer-container">
          <div class="notch-inner-container">
            <div class="left-face-notch notch"></div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="number-outer-container">
          <div class="number-inner-container">
            <div class="number-banner">2</div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- -->

      <div class="step-container" style="margin-top:50px;">

        <div class="content-box"></div>



        <div class="notch-outer-container">
          <div class="notch-inner-container">
            <div class="left-face-notch notch"></div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="number-outer-container">
          <div class="number-inner-container">
            <div class="number-banner">4</div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- -->

      <div class="step-container" style="margin-top:50px;">

        <div class="content-box"></div>



        <div class="notch-outer-container">
          <div class="notch-inner-container">
            <div class="left-face-notch notch"></div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="number-outer-container">
          <div class="number-inner-container">
            <div class="number-banner"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- -->
    </div>


  </div>
  <!-- .wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- .wrapper-big -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `position:relative` to the parent container, and set `position:absolute` on the child element, so they will always stay together.

Read this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426497/position-relative-vs-position-absolute)** if you're interested in learning more about the details of how `position` works.

<kbd>**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7dte3ru6/10/)**</kbd>

```
.cell .step-container {
    position: relative;
}
.cell .number-outer-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.left-cell .number-outer-container {
    left: 390px;
}
.right-cell .number-outer-container {
    left: -20px;
}
.left-face-notch,
.right-face-notch {
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px; /*200/2 - 30/2*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of `div.notch-outer-container` and `div.content-box`, are taking up all the space. And since all the divs are `inline-block`.

If you set `position:absolute; top:0;` on `div.number-outer-container` and remove `position:relative` then it goes up.

**http://jsfiddle.net/7dte3ru6/5/**

Comment: I was earlier using `position:absolute` on `.number-outer-container`, but then the div was scrolling with the scrolling of the page, and was not staying where it was, [here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1abv3gru/). In your fiddle, it is still below its parent. Still +1 for answering the question.

Comment: About " div.notch-outer-container and div.content-box, are taking up all the space.", I am sorry I had posted a code before an update I had made in which I removed the margin from the `.notch-outer-container`, then I edited the question, now the code in the question is updated.

Comment: put this `position:relative` on `div.step-container`. Absolutely positioned elements use closest parent with position relative as a reference.

Comment: Thank you so very much, especially for including the reason in your answer "Absolutely positioned elements use closest parent with position relative as a reference." The abover answerer had already solved it, and I had already requested them to post it as answer so I could accept it, otherwise I would definitely accept this answer. Thank you very much.