# Div is not in the place it should be

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get a `<div>` to stay on the bottom of another `<div>`, but so far it only goes to the bottom of the browser - instead of bottom of the `<div>`. Here's the code I've tried:

```
<div id="header">


<div style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;left: 0;height: 15;text-align: left;width: 100%;background: url(images/btrans.png);"><b>Driftsmelding: </b><font style="color: #88d327;"></font></div>
</div>
```

and the css part

```
#header {
    background: url(images/logo_oslo.jpg);
    background-position: 0px -12px;
}
#header {
    background: url(images/logo.jpg);
    background-position: 0px -12px;
    margin: 25px auto 0px auto;
    width: 1092px;
    height: 140px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #333333;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px #000;
    border-top-left-radius: 14px;
    border-top-right-radius: 14px;
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be? I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to use position `absolute`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `position: relative;` to the `#header` see fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/sxh0n7d1/2/

```
#header {
    background: url(images/logo_oslo.jpg);
    background-position: 0px -12px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is a good explanation of the difference between `relative` and `absolute` [Position Relative vs Position Absolute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426497/position-relative-vs-position-absolute)