# How can you change the position of <div> block?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know how can I change the position of  block

Here's a code:

```
<div style="background-color:#COLOR;width: px;height: px;">
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Is it

```
position:absolute;
right: px;
```

?
I've tested it out too but without a result it didn't work sadly.

Comment: First, you have to go [through the basics](https://www.w3schools.com/css/)

Please fullfill it, this question can be resolved in a tutorial.

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? You need to be more specific in your question. Also, why are your 'width' and 'height' empty?

Comment: 1.  Why are all the pixel values missing.  2.  What is your actual question and problem - it is very unclear what you have attempted to do and what is not working about it.  Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position Relative vs Position Absolute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426497/position-relative-vs-position-absolute)

Answer (score 0):

if you set,

```
position : absolute
```

you can use `left : value; right : value; top : value; bottom : value;`

to change your block position .

if its `relative` , you can use `margin :` instead

Answer (score 0):

you must set position:relative and then set right and top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use float: right. You should look up for how to position elements​ using float. Remember to `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after using two float div.

Answer (score 0):

The top div must be relative.

And you can change or add: bottom, left, right and top values..

For exp. :

```
<div style="position:relative; width:100px; height:100px;background-color:#6d0808;">
  <div style="background-color:#d3d3d3; padding:10px; position:absolute; right: -62px; bottom: 15px; ">
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to be more specific for what you want. i wrote a simple style in here for you 
HTML

```
<div class="sample">
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sample{
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  background:#000;
  position:absolute;
  right:100px;
}

.sample p{
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
}
```

if you want to learn about position property please visit https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp