# Aligning an image towards the right in css/bootstrap

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position, absolute

I have a screenshot as shown below which I am trying to replicate in HTML, CSS and JS.

`The screenshot should remain the same both for mobile and desktop version`.

[image]

At this moment, I am working on the three dots (as marked on the image above) aligned towards the right.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5a89bd3d/8/embedded/result/) for it with HTML and CSS codes. I have created an image for the three dots.  The code which I have used in order to align three dots image towards the right is:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="nav-top-searchbar">
    <form>
        <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <input type="text" name="search">
        <img src="https://s9.postimg.org/d6s4xvykv/Ellipsis.png" id="ellipsis">
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#ellipsis {
    top: -30px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1320px;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

The problem in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5a89bd3d/8/embedded/result/) is when I am seeing the web-page in the mobile version, `it is creating a white space all the way towards the right`. I am wondering what changes do I need to make in the above CSS code/HTML code so that I don't see any white space on the right.

Answer (score 1):

I would have advice you put the image in a div container but try this

## ellipsis {

```
top: -30px; position: absolute ; right:0; }
```

Comment: Still there is white space. Can you provide the fiddle for it ?

Comment: Is the containing div having relative position??  I mean the class nav-top-searchbar??

Comment: No. I have included all the CSS codes related to that div.

Comment: Do that div need to have position relative or bottom ?

Comment: Try this put both the span and input field in a single div and put the image in a separate div. Create a class for both div's. In the both class add make the display inline-block then on the first div the one one containing both span and text input set the float property to left.

Comment: No just try what I just sent let me know how far. Remember two separate div's.

Comment: According to your comment, this is what I have done in the HTML:


`<div class="nav-top-searchbar">
<div class="searchicon">
        <form>
            <span class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <input type="text" name="search">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class=ellipsis>
        <img src="/assets/images/Ellipsis.png">
    </div>

</div>`

Can you write the CSS ? I am having difficulty understanding it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168514/discussion-between-user5447339-and-friday-ameh).

Comment: Is this the HTML you want me to use ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168515/discussion-between-friday-ameh-and-user5447339).

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

## 1) The `#ellipsis` itself

```
#ellipsis {
    top: 12px; // Sounds good and a bit centered [ Vertically ]
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px; // Increase or decrease it depends on your UI needs
}
```

### Why did I change here?

1. `top` from negative to positive.
2. `position` from `relative` to `absolute` as we would give `relative` position to the `<input>` itself. Because we need to be wrapped inside it. If you are confused about `relative` and `absolute` take a quick look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10426566/5560399).
3. Instead of using `left: 1320px;` we used `right` to stick it at the right

## 2) The `#ellipsis` container / The `.nav-top-searchbar`

```
.nav-top-searchbar {
    position: relative;
}
```

> Your code might work fine without adding this, but **I highly recommend you adding this to avoid any styling issues now or even later.** Some browsers might run it fine - *As it works now with my without adding it* - but you should consider adding the `relative` to the parent to keep your image inside of it.

---

Apply the changes above and let me know if you got any further questions!

Comment: I am applying those changes. Will get back to you once I am done. Can you edit your changes in the fiddle ?

Comment: Ok, its look extremely good in the desktop view. No spacing at the right. Thanks. 

.....In the mobile view for different mobile phones (iphone 6/7/8 plus, iphone 6/7/8, Pixel 2, Pixel 2 XL ) I can see some space at the right whereas in Galaxy S5 and IPhone 5/SE mobile phones I can see fair amount of space towards the right. Is there any to fix it ?

Comment: Glad it works!

I noticed that you have `border` in your `<input>`. Try to delete it and check it again, let me know if you see a white space again!

Comment: Border in your <input>. In HTML. I have used`<input type="text" name="search">` and in CSS, I have used
`input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    background: #10314c;
}`

Are you asking me to remove `background: #10314c;`  ?

Comment: Obviously, you didn't add it yourself. But the browser did.
Write `border: none` to your `<input>`. Or reset any border made automatically by the browsers from all your elements with:
* {
 border: none
}

Comment: Ok, In the CSS, if I am using `input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    //    background: #10314c;
    border: none;
}`

then search-bar goes off from the webpage. But if I use 

`input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    background: #10314c;
    border: none;
}`

the spacing remains the same as in the previous fiddle send by you. Can you send me the updated fiddle ? As I am confused in your comment.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of that space?

Answer (score 0):

I would float that element right with `float: right;`

Comment: By using float:right, the content below the search bar seems to change its position.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
   #ellipsis {
         top: -30px; 
         position: absolute; 
         right:0;
   }
```

Comment: I am still seeing the white-space by using your code. Can you provide the fiddle for it ?

Comment: If you see in the full screen, three dots image is not there where it should be. Also, in the mobile view, I can see the white space on the right.