# Create text inside an image

Tags: html, css, less

I want to make text in an image. I have tried to follow the rules in [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp) but it did not show satisfactory results

This is the final result shown:
[image: Reality Image]

The following code below is the LESS code that was created:

```
body {
  background: url("../img/background-blur-5px.jpg") no-repeat top right fixed;
  .container{
    position: relative;
    .img-bg {
      margin: auto auto;
      display: block;
      width: 70%;
      position: relative;
      @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
        display: none;
      }
    }
    .login-box{
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
        background: white;
        width: 90%;
        height: 30em;
        margin: 2em 0;
        padding: 1em;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the HTML code that was created:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="{{url('image/sbopays')}}/login-box.png" class="img-bg">
  <div class="login-box">
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the desired expectation:
[image: Ekspektasi]

What am I forgot so I can add it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the final answer.
My code was right, but with one step further, I just need more positioning with `left` `right` `top` and `bottom` style:

```
.login-box{
   position: absolute;
   top: 3em;
   left: 54%;
   right: 20%;
   text-align: left;
   @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
       background: white;
       position: relative;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       width: 90%;
       height: 30em;
       margin: 2em 0;
       padding: 1em;
       }
}
```

Final Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**CSS positioning will be the right solution for your expectation.**
As per the position rule, the parent container should have **position: relative** and child tag should have **position:absolute**.

Now you have applied relative to the image tag instead of the div tag.
please check this link to know about CSS positioning method.  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426497/position-relative-vs-absolute)

```
.container{position:relative;}
```

if you have any doubt please let me know.

Comment: I already use CSS positioning and it finally worked with further explanation on my answer

Answer (score 0):

The container position should be relative if the content inside is absolute:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: @MirukuSheki post a jsfiddle link to help you better

Comment: I tried to post it to jsfiddle, but I can't upload the images