# Footer is not staying at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

I am creating a portfolio website from scratch. I am stuck on the footer part. The footer I have created for other pages works as intended but for the Resume page it stays in the middle of the page rather than at the bottom of the page. I have already tried to search for similar problem and try their solutions but sadly it didn't work for me.

Here is my HTML code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <title> Game Programmer </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset-fonts-grids.css"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resume.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="project.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div id = "container">
        <div id="doc2" class="yui-t7">
        <div id="inner">

            <div id="hd">
                <div class="yui-gc">
                    <div class="yui-u first">
                        <h1>a</h1>
                        <h2>Game Programmer</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="yui-u">
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <h3><a id="pdf" href="#">Download PDF</a></h3>
                            <h3><a href="mailto:1@gmail.com">1@gmail.com</a></h3>
                        </div><!--// .contact-info -->
                    </div>
                </div><!--// .yui-gc -->
            </div><!--// hd -->

            <div id="bd">
                <div id="yui-main">
                    <div class="yui-b">

                        <div class="yui-gf">
                            <div class="yui-u first">
                                <h2>Profile</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="yui-u">
                                <p class="enlarge">
                                    Game Programmer with 2+ years of experience with multiple game engine and a shipped AA title for PC and Consoles. Possesses a Masters in Game Programming.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--// .yui-gf -->

                        <div class="yui-gf">
                            <div class="yui-u first">
                                <h2>Skills</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="yui-u">

                                    <div class="talent">
                                        <h2>Time Management</h2>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="talent">
                                        <h2>Strong Work Ethics</h2>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="talent">
                                        <h2>Team Player</h2>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--// .yui-gf -->

                        <div class="yui-gf">
                            <div class="yui-u first">
                                <h2>Technical</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="yui-u">
                                <ul class="talent">
                                    <li>C</li>
                                    <li class="last">C++</li>
                                </ul>

                                <ul class="talent">
                                    <li>C#</li>
                                    <li class="last">Unity</li>
                                </ul>

                                <ul class="talent">
                                    <li>Unreal Engine 4</li>
                                    <li class="last">SVN / Perforce</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--// .yui-gf-->

                        <div class="yui-gf">

                            <div class="yui-u first">
                                <h2>Experience</h2>
                            </div><!--// .yui-u -->

                            <div class="yui-u">

                                <div class="job">
                                    <h2>a</h2>
                                    <h3>b</h3>
                                    <h4>c</h4>
                                    <p>d</p>
    <p>•e</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="job">
                                    <h2>a</h2>
                                    <h3>b</h3>
                                    <h4>c</h4>
                                    <p>d</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="job last">
                                    <h2>a</h2>
                                    <h3>b</h3>
                                    <h4>c</h4>
                                    <p>d</p>
                                    <p>e</p>
                                </div>

                            </div><!--// .yui-u -->
                        </div><!--// .yui-gf -->


                        <div class="yui-gf last">
                            <div class="yui-u first">
                                <h2>Education</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="yui-u">
                                <h2>a</h2>
                                <h3>b</h3>
                            </div>

                            <div class="yui-u">
                                <h2>a</h2>
                                <h3>b</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--// .yui-gf -->


                    </div><!--// .yui-b -->
                </div><!--// yui-main -->
            </div><!--// bd -->

        </div><!-- // inner -->
        </div><!--// doc -->
        
        <!--Footer-->
        <footer class="social-footer">
            <div class="social-footer-icons">
                <ul class="menu-simple">
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=en"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is CSS code

```
body {
    background: url(Images/px_by_Gre3g.png);
    font: 16px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; color: #636363;
}

/* //-- yui-grids style overrides -- */
#inner { padding: 10px 80px; margin: 80px auto; background: #f5f5f5; border: solid #666; border-width: 8px 0 2px 0; }
.yui-gf { margin-bottom: 2em; padding-bottom: 2em; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }

/* //-- header, body, footer -- */
#hd { margin: 2.5em 0 3em 0; padding-bottom: 1.5em; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc }
#hd h2 { text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px; }
#bd, #ft { margin-bottom: 2em; }

/* //-- footer -- */
#ft { padding: 1em 0 5em 0; font-size: 92%; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; }
#ft p { margin-bottom: 0; text-align: centezr;   }

/* //-- core typography and style -- */
#hd h1 { font-size: 48px; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 3px; margin-bottom: 10px;}
h2 { font-size: 152% }
h3, h4 { font-size: 122%; }
h1, h2, h3, h4 { color: #333; }
p { font-size: 100%; line-height: 18px; padding-right: 3em; }
a { color: #990003 }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
strong { font-weight: bold; }
li { line-height: 24px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
p.enlarge { font-size: 144%; padding-right: 6.5em; line-height: 24px; }
p.enlarge span { color: #000 }
.contact-info { margin-top: 7px; }
.first h2 { font-style: italic; }
.last { border-bottom: 0 }


/* //-- section styles -- */

a#pdf { display: block; float: left; background: #666; color: white; padding: 6px 50px 6px 12px; margin-bottom: 6px; text-decoration: none;  }
a#pdf:hover { background: #222; }

.job { position: relative; margin-bottom: 1em; padding-bottom: 1em; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
.job h4 { position: absolute; top: 0.35em; right: 0 }
.job h3 {margin-top : 5px; margin-bottom : 10px;}

.last { border: none; }
.skills-list ul { margin: 0; }
.skills-list li { margin: 3px 0; padding: 3px 0; }
.skills-list li span { font-size: 152%; display: block; margin-bottom: -2px; padding: 0 }
.talent { width: 32%; float: left }
.talent h2 { margin-bottom: 6px; }

#srt-ttab { margin-bottom: 100px; text-align: center;  }
#srt-ttab img.last { margin-top: 20px }

/* --// override to force 1/8th width grids -- */
.yui-gf .yui-u{width:80.2%; padding-bottom: 20px;}
.yui-gf div.first{width:12.3%;}



ul#nav{
    width: 1300px; list-style: none; overflow: hidden; margin: 80px 18em 0 auto;
}
#nav li {
    width: 100px; height: 35px; float: left; padding: 13px 0 0 0;
    background: url(Images/nav-bg.png);
    font-weight: bold; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#nav li:nth-child(1) {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
#nav li:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
#nav li:nth-child(3) {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
ul#nav li:nth-child(4) {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
ul#nav li a.active {
    color:cadetblue;  
    text-decoration: underline ;

}
ul#nav li a {
    color: #616369; text-decoration: none;
}
ul#nav li a:hover {
    color: #a12121;
}
#container {
    width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 250px;
}
.menu-simple {
    margin:auto;
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu-simple li {
    font-size:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100px;
    margin:0;
    padding:12px 0;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    height:40px;
}
footer {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding:10px 0 auto 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.social-footer {
    bottom:20px;
    background: #8a8a8a;
    height:50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: inherit;
}

.social-footer .social-footer-icons .fa {
      font-size: 30px;
      color: #fefefe;
}

.social-footer .social-footer-icons .fa:hover {
      color: #4a4a4a;
      transition: color 0.15s ease-in;
}
```

I am not a web designer so don't mind messy code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to change the position of both footer and .social-footer to 'relative' instead of 'absolute'

```
footer {
    text-align: center;
    //position: absolute;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    padding:10px 0 auto 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.social-footer {
    bottom:20px;
    background: #8a8a8a;
    height:50px;
    position: relative;
    //position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: inherit;
}
```

This Stackoverflow thread seems to explain the difference between the two and when to use both.

[Position Relative vs Absolute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426497/position-relative-vs-absolute)

Answer (score 1):

change your social-footer class like this :

```
.social-footer {
    background: #8a8a8a;
    height:50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: inherit;
}
```

```css
body {
    background: url(Images/px_by_Gre3g.png);
    font: 16px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; color: #636363;
}

/* //-- yui-grids style overrides -- */
#inner { padding: 10px 80px; margin: 80px auto; background: #f5f5f5; border: solid #666; border-width: 8px 0 2px 0; }
.yui-gf { margin-bottom: 2em; padding-bottom: 2em; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }

/* //-- header, body, footer -- */
#hd { margin: 2.5em 0 3em 0; padding-bottom: 1.5em; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc }
#hd h2 { text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px; }
#bd, #ft { margin-bottom: 2em; }

/* //-- footer -- */
#ft { padding: 1em 0 5em 0; font-size: 92%; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; }
#ft p { margin-bottom: 0; text-align: centezr;   }

/* //-- core typography and style -- */
#hd h1 { font-size: 48px; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 3px; margin-bottom: 10px;}
h2 { font-size: 152% }
h3, h4 { font-size: 122%; }
h1, h2, h3, h4 { color: #333; }
p { font-size: 100%; line-height: 18px; padding-right: 3em; }
a { color: #990003 }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
strong { font-weight: bold; }
li { line-height: 24px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
p.enlarge { font-size: 144%; padding-right: 6.5em; line-height: 24px; }
p.enlarge span { color: #000 }
.contact-info { margin-top: 7px; }
.first h2 { font-style: italic; }
.last { border-bottom: 0 }


/* //-- section styles -- */

a#pdf { display: block; float: left; background: #666; color: white; padding: 6px 50px 6px 12px; margin-bottom: 6px; text-decoration: none;  }
a#pdf:hover { background: #222; }

.job { position: relative; margin-bottom: 1em; padding-bottom: 1em; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
.job h4 { position: absolute; top: 0.35em; right: 0 }
.job h3 {margin-top : 5px; margin-bottom : 10px;}

.last { border: none; }
.skills-list ul { margin: 0; }
.skills-list li { margin: 3px 0; padding: 3px 0; }
.skills-list li span { font-size: 152%; display: block; margin-bottom: -2px; padding: 0 }
.talent { width: 32%; float: left }
.talent h2 { margin-bottom: 6px; }

#srt-ttab { margin-bottom: 100px; text-align: center;  }
#srt-ttab img.last { margin-top: 20px }

/* --// override to force 1/8th width grids -- */
.yui-gf .yui-u{width:80.2%; padding-bottom: 20px;}
.yui-gf div.first{width:12.3%;}



ul#nav{
    width: 1300px; list-style: none; overflow: hidden; margin: 80px 18em 0 auto;
}
#nav li {
    width: 100px; height: 35px; float: left; padding: 13px 0 0 0;
    background: url(Images/nav-bg.png);
    font-weight: bold; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#nav li:nth-child(1) {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
#nav li:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
#nav li:nth-child(3) {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
ul#nav li:nth-child(4) {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
ul#nav li a.active {
    color:cadetblue;  
    text-decoration: underline ;

}
ul#nav li a {
    color: #616369; text-decoration: none;
}
ul#nav li a:hover {
    color: #a12121;
}
#container {
    width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 250px;
}
.menu-simple {
    margin:auto;
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu-simple li {
    font-size:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100px;
    margin:0;
    padding:12px 0;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    height:40px;
}
footer {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding:10px 0 auto 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.social-footer {
    background: #8a8a8a;
    height:50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: inherit;
}

.social-footer .social-footer-icons .fa {
      font-size: 30px;
      color: #fefefe;
}

.social-footer .social-footer-icons .fa:hover {
      color: #4a4a4a;
      transition: color 0.15s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <title> Game Programmer </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset-fonts-grids.css"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resume.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="project.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id = "container">
        <div id="doc2" class="yui-t7">
        <div id="inner">

            <div id="hd">
                <div class="yui-gc">
                    <div class="yui-u first">
                        <h1>a</h1>
                        <h2>Game Programmer</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="yui-u">
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <h3><a id="pdf" href="#">Download PDF</a></h3>
                            <h3><a href="mailto:1@gmail.com">1@gmail.com</a></h3>
                        </div><!--// .contact-info -->
                    </div>
                </div><!--// .yui-gc -->
            </div><!--// hd -->

            <div id="bd">
                <div id="yui-main">
                    <div class="yui-b">

                        <div class="yui-gf">
                            <div class="yui-u first">
                                <h2>Profile</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="yui-u">
                                <p class="enlarge">
                                    Game Programmer with 2+ years of experience with multiple game engine and a shipped AA title for PC and Consoles. Possesses a Masters in Game Programming.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--// .yui-gf -->

                        <div class="yui-gf">
                            <div class="yui-u first">
                                <h2>Skills</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="yui-u">

                                    <div class="talent">
                                        <h2>Time Management</h2>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="talent">
                                        <h2>Strong Work Ethics</h2>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="talent">
                                        <h2>Team Player</h2>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--// .yui-gf -->

                        <div class="yui-gf">
                            <div class="yui-u first">
                                <h2>Technical</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="yui-u">
                                <ul class="talent">
                                    <li>C</li>
                                    <li class="last">C++</li>
                                </ul>

                                <ul class="talent">
                                    <li>C#</li>
                                    <li class="last">Unity</li>
                                </ul>

                                <ul class="talent">
                                    <li>Unreal Engine 4</li>
                                    <li class="last">SVN / Perforce</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--// .yui-gf-->

                        <div class="yui-gf">

                            <div class="yui-u first">
                                <h2>Experience</h2>
                            </div><!--// .yui-u -->

                            <div class="yui-u">

                                <div class="job">
                                    <h2>a</h2>
                                    <h3>b</h3>
                                    <h4>c</h4>
                                    <p>d</p>
    <p>•e</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="job">
                                    <h2>a</h2>
                                    <h3>b</h3>
                                    <h4>c</h4>
                                    <p>d</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="job last">
                                    <h2>a</h2>
                                    <h3>b</h3>
                                    <h4>c</h4>
                                    <p>d</p>
                                    <p>e</p>
                                </div>

                            </div><!--// .yui-u -->
                        </div><!--// .yui-gf -->


                        <div class="yui-gf last">
                            <div class="yui-u first">
                                <h2>Education</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="yui-u">
                                <h2>a</h2>
                                <h3>b</h3>
                            </div>

                            <div class="yui-u">
                                <h2>a</h2>
                                <h3>b</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--// .yui-gf -->


                    </div><!--// .yui-b -->
                </div><!--// yui-main -->
            </div><!--// bd -->

        </div><!-- // inner -->
        </div><!--// doc -->

        <!--Footer-->
        <footer class="social-footer">
            <div class="social-footer-icons">
                <ul class="menu-simple">
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=en"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this tag to your css made everything seem okay for me!

```
html {
  position: relative;
}
```

I used this as a reference: [How can I position my div at the bottom of its container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/how-can-i-position-my-div-at-the-bottom-of-its-container)

Comment: Ok will try it out

Answer (score 0):

Some other folks have already pointed out that you need to have position set to relative, left set to 0, and only one value defined for the 'bottom' property. I don't want to steal their thunder. While looking through your code, I noticed that a lot of dimensions are hard-coded, though, and you seem to be doing your grid system from scratch. I think you could save yourself a lot of headache and make your page look more professional if you include this

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in your header and define your dimensions in 'vw' (meaning "percent of view width") instead of px. You would probably be better off than that, even, if you were to at least reuse the grid system from Bootstrap, even if you don't want any styling from the rest of the framework.

Comment: Okay, I will try it out. I am not HTML programmer, so I try to look around to find what I want and then try to replicate it. That is why most of my pages aren't that consistent and I know it will bite me back in the future, but I have to make this portfolio ASAP.

Thanks a lot for info.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the position from absolute to fixed

```
footer {
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    padding:10px 0 auto 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.social-footer {
    bottom:20px;
    background: #8a8a8a;
    height:50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: inherit;
}
```