# Overlap an img completely with another div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to achieve this effect where a photo gets a repeating pattern overlayed over the entire photo when the user place his mouse over the photo.

**Problem:** I do not seem to be able to make the overlay div overlay the photo completely. How should this be done?

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KDyKH/2/

**Edit:** Updated the fiddle

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    background: blue;
}

.photo_box {
    padding: 8px 10px 11px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 6px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    box-shadow:         1px 1px 6px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.photo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.photo_tint {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    background: red;
    -moz-opacity: 0.70;
    opacity: 0.70;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=70);
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="photo_box">
        <img src='http://www.kurzweilai.net/images/Google-logo.jpg' class="photo">
            <div class="photo_tint"></div>
        </img>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to adding `left` and `top` properties to `.photo_tint`, you also need to make `.photo_box` relatively positioned (it wasn't before you edited your question).

```
.photo_box {
    position: relative;
}

.photo_tint {
    left:0;
    right:0;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KDyKH/5/

The absolute position's left/top/right/bottom attributes work off the last element higher in the hierarchy with position set to relative or absolute. If no parent elements have position set to relative/absolute, the body is used. In your case, the closest relatively positioned element was `#container`, so when `left` and `top` were set on `.photo_tint` it used `#container`'s origin and not `.photo_box`'s origin as needed to achieve the desired effect.

Additionally, if an element is set to position:absolute, and no left/top/right/right properties are set, the element will not behave as absolute [(see this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243991/position-absolute-without-setting-top-left-bottom-right).

Answer (score 1):

```
.photo_tint {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    background: red;
    top:0; left:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
}​
```

???

http://jsfiddle.net/tFbbM/1/

Comment: Oh, I dont want to cover the white part, just the image. I tried changing the top and left, but it suddenly jumped if top is not 0. In addition, the red overlay is as wide as the white box, I just need it to be as wide as the photo. http://jsfiddle.net/KDyKH/6/

Answer (score 0):

z-index:-1 on the image or z-index:2 on the div

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: blue;
}

.photo {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}

.photo_tint {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    top:0px;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Just position the `photo_tint` div using `top` and `left`. http://jsfiddle.net/OhMrBigshot/gEdJu/

Comment: I updated my jsfiddle to more accurately reflect the scenario http://jsfiddle.net/KDyKH/2/