# How is the css property top calculated for absolute elements that do not set the property themselves?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [position: absolute without setting top/left/bottom/right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243991/position-absolute-without-setting-top-left-bottom-right)

Looking at the following code, I have div#box2 that has position: absolute set on it. It is in between two divs that have position: static set on them. Based on the following code, I would expect div#box2 to be at the top left of the body element. However, when it is rendered it receives a top value placing it beneath box1. Why does this happen?

I understand that when I explicitly set the top value of div#box2 to 0px, it appears at the top. I just don't know why it is not computed to 0px by the browser to begin with.

Here is some sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Position Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body { background-color: #DEDEDE; }
      #content { border: solid; }
      #content div { height: 150px; opacity: .7;}
      #box1 { background-color: red; }
      #box2 { background-color: yellow; }
      #box3 { background-color: lightblue; }

    #content div { width: 150px; }
        #box2 { position: absolute; text-align: right;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="box1"><span>1</span></div>
      <div id="box2"><span>2</span></div>
      <div id="box3"><span>3</span></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want div box 2 at place of div box 1?

Comment: why there is no div that is set to ´position:relative´?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an element is given position absolute it is taken out of the flow allowing other elements to be placed above or below it.  Without explicitly setting a top value, the top value will retain the elements position had it not be removed from the flow.

If we switch the order of the boxes you can see this taking place as `#box2` is completely removed from the flow and sits outside of `#content` but still stacks where it would be if it had `position:static`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Position Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body { background-color: #DEDEDE; }
      #content { border: solid; }
      #content div { height: 150px; opacity: .7;}
      #box1 { background-color: red; }
      #box2 { background-color: yellow; }
      #box3 { background-color: lightblue; }

    #content div { width: 150px; }
        #box2 { position: absolute; text-align: right;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="box1"><span>1</span></div>
      <div id="box3"><span>3</span></div>
      <div id="box2"><span>2</span></div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any documentation/articles/anything explaining "Without explicitly setting a top value, the top value will retain the elements position had it not be removed from the flow?" Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The *default* value of `top` is "[auto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/auto)", not "0" ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/top)), therefore it *should not* be positioned at the top of the `<body>` element.

As for *why* "auto" translates to "same position as if `position` was `static`", see the [CSS specification on positioning](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-positioning/#abs-non-replaced-height) (emphasis mine):

> For absolutely positioned elements, the used values of the vertical dimensions must satisfy this constraint:
>
> 'top' + 'margin-top' + 'border-top-width' + 'padding-top' + 'height' + 'padding-bottom' + 'border-bottom-width' + 'margin-bottom' + 'bottom' = height of containing block
>
> *If all three of ‘top’, ‘height’, and ‘bottom’ are ‘auto’: First set any ‘auto’ values for ‘margin-top’ and ‘margin-bottom’ to ‘0’, then **set ‘top’ to the static position**, and finally apply rule number three below.*
>
> ...

Comment: so use `top: 0px;` `left 0px;` ..nice 1 mate..

Comment: I understand that top's default value is auto. I am merely confused why the auto value calculated places div#box2 beneath div#box1. Reading [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position), it says an absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its nearest positioned ancestor. I assumed that would mean the absolutely positioned element would auto calculate a top value of 0 since it is relative to the nearest positioned element. Your answer is correct, but I'm going with @Jrod because he explains how the top value is getting calculated.