# Working with the CSS pseudo element after

Tags: css, wordpress, css-position, pseudo-element

I am working with WordPress and adding a menu to it, and I am trying to add some content after each nav button. Ideally I wanted to add an extra `<li>` tag after each nav button to act as the background spacer, but seems you can't do that with `:after`.

I then tried another method of just using something like this..

```
#header .nav li:after {
    content: " ";
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    min-width: 2px;
    height: 45px;
    min-height: 45px;
    background: url('images/nav-button-spacer-bg.png') left top no-repeat;    
}
```

That ended up with the spacer being in the correct position horizontally, but not vertically, as it was placed directly under the menu.

I fixed that by changing the `position` to `absolute` and adding `top: 0px;`.

This appears to have fixed it, however I'm wondering if this is right as both the `ul` tag and the containing `div` element both have a `position` of `static` and I'm wondering how the now `absolute` item is sticking to them.

I'm guessing pseudo elements work differently and hence why it doesn't need the parent element to have a position of `fixed, relative or absolute`.

Am I right in my thinking and is this the best way to do what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfectly fine way! I suppose you just missed an element with actually did have `position: relative;` on it. See this example for a demonstration of absolute positioned pseudo elements: http://jsfiddle.net/mytJ3/

But you should notice that if you have a absolute positioned element and ommit some of the `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` properties the position calculating will some how fallback to a way as if the element were static positioned. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10244977/723769

Comment: Ahh yes, just recalled that since the content is placed *inside* the element and not *next* to it as another element, this means it's parent element would be the respective `li` tag, which I have set to `relative`. :) Thanks for the answer! :)