# Element with fixed position

Tags: css, position

I need to have my element's position set to fixed because I want to use it as a header in scrollable div. I also need to specify the elements poisition at top:0 and right:0

If I use those properties together it doesnt work. How can I solve this;

```
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
```

works but I need to have position fixed..

If I use position fixed the div is position over the whole document not inside my div where I append it...

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/TP2cp/

Comment: Use `position: fixed`...

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243991/position-absolute-without-setting-top-left-bottom-right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:fixed`.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="header"><p>Header</p></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main{
    width:100%;
    height:2000px;
}

#header{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;left:0;
    background:yellow;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8Y3q/).

**UPDATE**

A solution with `width:inherit;` :

[JSFiddle#2](http://jsfiddle.net/TP2cp/4/).

Comment: This works but my header is displayed over the whole document not inside my div where I append it.

Comment: @Jacob You can try to put the _fixed_ div outside the _parent_ div. [exampe](http://jsfiddle.net/m8Y3q/1/).

Comment: Can you check my example in the wuestion which has all the correct css I want

Comment: Yes like that except one thing.. the width of the parent is dynamic. If I set width to 100% it will expand my div to the whole page.

Comment: @Jacob you can do that with pure **CSS** because _position:fixed;_ puts the element out of its flow, but with JS you can. Solution with [JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/TP2cp/2/).

Comment: @Jacob I stand corrected ! A solution with **pure CSS** and **width:inherit** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TP2cp/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Who said you couldn't use those properties together?

```
position:fixed;
top:0;
right:0;
```

Try it out yourself in this example jsFiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/KDZQz/).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="theDiv">Example Div</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#theDiv { position:fixed; top:0px; right:250px; }
```

---

**In reply to OP's edit:**

You can't have a fixed positoned div inside a container div like that, as making it a fixed div **will take it out of the flow**. You should use `position:absolute` inside of a container div with `position:relative` if you plan on having it fixed inside another div.

Take a look at my new jsFiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/HFjU6/932/).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    Container Div
    <div id="fixed">Child Div</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width: 400px;
    position:relative;
}

#fixed {
   position:absolute;
   top:0px;
   right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
position:fixed;
top:0;
right:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is how did you positioned the scrollable div? if I have understand what you want I think you just need to put the header outside the scrollable div