# Child position absolute parent relative doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to implement something like a web page navbar. I have code like this:

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-right {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h2>My First Website</h2>
  <ul class="nav-right">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I have known that an absolute element is positioned to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element. I have set position property of element nav as absolute, but it looks like the `<ul>` run out of the `<nav>` range.  In other word  **i'm confused about why nav'height  is  less than  ul's**   Thanks a  lot.

[image]

Comment: try `top : 0px;` with that.IF the top is auto then it defaults to their position

Comment: By `<nav position: relative>` you mean `<nav style="position: relative">`, right?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand everything about your problem, but the last statement sounds like you might need `overflow: hidden;` in `nav`.

Comment: Sorry about i didn't  describe my problem clearly because  my  terrible english.   `<nav position: relative>` truely mean that  i have set  property position  of element nav  as  absolute.@Xufox

Comment: Thanks for editing my question to make it looks better @Xufox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute position elements are removed from the document flow. So the parent's height will hold only the other elements. Not the absolute position elements.

If you want your parent to cover your absolute position element then you have to set a fixed height to the parent element. You can set top: 0; like other's have answered. But still your parent's height wont be determined by the absolute positioned element, that's the reason the ul is outside the nav.

Comment: Thanks  a lot,  this is  the  answer  I'm  looking for.  By the way, my english is too  terrible to describe  my confusion  clear  but you truely  understand  what i mean.

Answer (score 1):

try `top : 0px;` also with that.If the top is auto then it defaults to their  `position: static` values.Check this for more details:[position: absolute without setting top/left/bottom/right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243991/position-absolute-without-setting-top-left-bottom-right)

Also `display:block` for the `nav` for the `nav` to take full sapce

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.nav-right {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <h2>My First Website</h2>
      <ul class="nav-right">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I have tried but i found that  it looks like  element <ul>   is still  out of  its  parent element <nav>

Comment: Thanks  XYZ,  your code  works  but @karthick truely point out the core problem so i  have to vote him.  Thanks  again :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: block;` in parent and add `top:0;` in child to align in right side of parent

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.nav-right {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top:0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h2>My First Website</h2>
  <ul class="nav-right">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks  jafarbtech,  your code  works  but @karthick truely point out the core problem so i  have to vote him.  Thanks  again :)

Answer (score 1):

**Try This :**

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-right {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
 <nav>
  <h2>My First Website</h2>
  <ul class="nav-right">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks  ehsan,  your code  works  but @karthick truely point out the core problem so i  have to vote him.  Thanks  again :)