# CSS absolute position orients on sibling rather than parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am a little confused about absolute positioning right now. I have always thought that if I position an element absolutely it would be positioned relative to it's parent element (in contrast to relative to it's usual position like  relative positioning). During homework I now came across this situation and I'm confused:

```
<body>
  <div> <!-- This is colored red in my example -->
    ...
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute;"> <!-- This is colored green in my example -->
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

What I would expect:
[image: What I expect]
What I got:
[image: What I got]

Of course when I set an actual position with `left`/`right`/`top`/`bottom` I get what I would expect from an absolutely positioned element. So is `position: absolute` just set to take the exact position it would be at without `position: absolute` when not specified otherwise?

Comment: If you don't reset the **top** position yep, it keep the space where he was original positioned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [position: absolute without setting top/left/bottom/right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243991/position-absolute-without-setting-top-left-bottom-right)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clarify:

> "I have always thought that if I position an element absolutely it would
>   be positioned relative to it's parent element"

Nope. If an element has `position: absolute;`, it is positioned relative to the nearest parent in the DOM chain that has `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` specified on it.  If no parents have it (ie. they are all `position: static`, which is the default), then it is positioned relative to the document (page).

When using position: absolute, always:

1. Be aware of what parent you want it positioned relative to, and make sure that parent has position: relative; on it.
2. Specify one or more of the top/right/bottom/left attributes on the absolutely positioned object.

Comment: This is not the answer the OP is looking for. He/she want's to know *why* this is not working when left/top/right/bottom is not set. Short answer: `position: absolute` has no effect when this is not set.

Comment: That isn't true.  Setting position: absolute; pops the element out of the normal flow.  Here is a codepen to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/morfie78/pen/mqoXem   You'll see that the first element has position: absolute; on it.  This pops that element out, and the second one gets moved up.  If you remove position: absolute; it goes back to normal.

Comment: I was just referring to another answer (which i linked as a "possible duplicate") in my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused with the difference between position and display.

Position will change which element your element will be positioned relative to.  In your case, your child div is now positioned to the body element.  That's why it's on top.

Also you need to be aware that div is displayed as block, which means it will take all the width.  If you want to align 2 divs left and right, the modern way is to use flexbox.  The old way is float left/right.

I have made an article to explain CSS position in details:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGN5CohGVTI