# Absolute element works inline (which should be block) in chrome

Tags: css, css-position

```css
.container {
  background: tan;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.inner {
  background: rgb(124, 182, 233);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  This is the long long text
  <span class="inner">This is the long long text</span>
  <!-- this is $0 -->
</div>
```

`getComputedStyle($0).display` return `block`, but the render result is inline in chrome(Version 119.0.6045.159 (Official Build) (arm64)).

Chrome:

[image: image1]

In Safari, it works as expected:

[image]

Comment: Not sure which of the two is actually to be considered "correct." Can you explain what you need this construct for? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @CBroe: It just confusing me. Setting `display: block` explicitly can solve the problem.

Comment: If you don't specify left, right, top, or bottom then the `position: absolute` property reverts back to `position: static` https://stackoverflow.com/a/10244977/12571484

Comment: @Adam - You've misunderstood that. It uses its _static position_. But it's still taken out of the flow, so anything following it will be placed as it wasn't there.